# Which SQL function I should use to repeat existing row values for a new column

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 column studentID and StudentName and department.

```
StudenID  StudentName Department
1          john         IT
2          Michael      Finance
3          Josh         chemical
```

I would like to create a view based on Student table where I would like to have StudentID,StudentName
and a Category Column that has 4 values as follows:

A,B,C,D

In the final view I would like to have above category assigned to each Student something like below

```
StudenID  StudentName Department   Category
1          john         IT         A
1          john         IT         B
1          john         IT         C
1          john         IT         D
2          Michael      Finance    A
2          Michael      Finance    B
2          Michael      Finance    C
2          Michael      Finance    D
3          Josh         chemical   A
3          Josh         chemical   B
3          Josh         chemical   C
3          Josh         chemical   D
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `cross join`.  In most databases you can do something like this:

```
select s.*, v.*
from students s cross join
     (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')) v(category);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `union`

```
select *,'A' as category from table 
union 
select *,'B' as category from table 
union
select *,'C' as category from table 
union
select *,'D' as category from table
```